# "Access Forbidden" message when attempting to change apache path

Tags: webserver, apache-http-server

This is on a fresh copy of Ubuntu. I tried to implement all of the solutions that I can find online but to no avail. Any ideas as to what is going on? This is the error message that I get:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is
>   either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Here is my permission file:

> Alias /bitnami/ "/home/avi/Dropbox/Field Team Tracker" Alias /bitnami
>   "/home/avi/Dropbox/Field Team Tracker"
>
> Options Indexes
>   +FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI   AllowOverride All   Order allow,deny   Allow from all

Here is my httpd.conf file:

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
# with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
# server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
# interpreted as '/log/access_log'.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/opt/lampp"

# 
# Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
# for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
# 
# Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
# mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
# other reason.
#
# Mutex default:logs

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8888

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<IfDefine JUSTTOMAKEAPXSHAPPY>
LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
</IfDefine>

<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin you@example.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:@@Port@@
# XAMPP
ServerName localhost

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

# 
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/home/avi/Dropbox/Field Team Tracker"
<Directory "/home/avi/Dropbox/Field Team Tracker">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    # XAMPP
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    Options Indexes All

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    #AllowOverride None
    # since XAMPP 1.4:
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    #DirectoryIndex index.html
    # XAMPP
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3 index.php4
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/opt/lampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig etc/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    # XAMPP, since LAMPP 0.9.8:
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    # XAMPP
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile etc/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
# returning the entire resource, or one of the special
# values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
# Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
#MaxRanges unlimited

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the etc/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include etc/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
Include etc/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include etc/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include etc/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include etc/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include etc/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
#Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include etc/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include etc/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
Include etc/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include etc/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
<IfModule ssl_module>
# XAMPP
<IfDefine SSL>
Include etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
</IfDefine>
</IfModule>
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

# XAMPP
Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
Include "/opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ErrorLog "logs/error_log" - as per config. This would've been a comment to [this answers comment-question](https://superuser.com/a/794800/331551) .. if I had the 50 reputation needed :-/
Also chmod o+x is not the required - or indeed clever - thing to do. chmod o+r would be for reading, directories, okay +x too.

Comment: ok, here is the error message:  
[core:error] [pid 9780] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:58881] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/avi/Dropbox/Field Team Tracker') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Comment: The basic solution is described on [Apache:Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) and your specific case of having apache-htdocs in a user-home on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244406/how-do-i-give-www-data-user-to-a-folder-in-my-home-folder) - HTH

Answer (score 0):

Since you've put your web content in /home, I'm guessing Apache simply doesn't have permission to access those files. i.e., I usually make Apache a member of the same group as the user who owns the home directory I want to publish, which allows Apache to read the files, but doesn't require them to be world readable. (Adding suexec to the mix allows you to then run applications as the user, so scripts can't poke around in other people's home directories, either.)

There should be more information in the log files (error.log, in particular) about what is wrong. If it's not a simple permissions/ownership problem, we'll need more information in order to help you solve it.

Comment: I already ran a chmod o+x on both my home directory and the project directory. Do you know where I can find the error file?

Comment: ok, here is the error message: [core:error] [pid 9780] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:58881] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/avi/Dropbox/Field Team Tracker') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Comment: The error indicates that one of the directories within the path is not readable by Apache. As I mentioned, I prefer to make Apache a member of the group of the user, so you don't have to open up permissions to all users. You'll run into problems later, most likely, if you go that route (suexec will refuse to run things with too-loose permissions, like you now have). This has the pleasant side effect that you probably don't need to micromanage permissions, since the umask will probably get it right for you by default.